# Joomla 1.5 - Hika Shop - domPDF, generate PDF blank Checkout Page

Tags: php, joomla, components

Joomla 1.5 with Hika Shop Plugin, Business License.

We are generating PDF Invoices resp. Documents after the customer clicks the checkoutbutton.
After this, a PDF is generated and will be attached to the confirmation eMail.

All works fine, the eMail is send but in the Frontend the Hika Shop return Page resp. the Hika Shop Checkout End Page will not be shown. Only a Blank Page is shown up.

I think the domPDF has a blocker thread but i dont know, how to turn it of.

The "$result = $this->mailer->Send();" doesn't give a result?!

```
//File: administrator/components/com_hikashop/classes/mail.php
//Function: function sendMail(&$mail){...

        $tmpBody = $this->mailer->Body;


    $dompdf = new DOMPDF();
    $dompdf->load_html($tmpBody);    
    $ThisTMP = $dompdf->render();

    $file_to_save = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/tmp/prototypes_order_'.rand(100000,999999).date( "H_i", time() + $mosConfig_offset * 60 * 60 ).'.pdf';

    //save the pdf file on the server
    $ThisTMP2 = file_put_contents($file_to_save, $dompdf->output()); 

    $this->mailer->AddAttachment($file_to_save);


    $result = $this->mailer->Send();



    if(!$result || !empty($result->message)){
        $this->mail_success = false;

    }
    if(!empty($result->message)){

    }

    return $result;
```

Answer (score 0):

Turn on error reporting in PHP.  When a php page encounters a fatal error, the page will not continue rendering.  I had a similar issue with an ssh function within the order.php page of another cart system, with the same thing happening as you are getting.

Once php error reporting is turned on, the page shouldn't be blank anymore, you should be getting a page with some errors (hopefully some fatal ones).  Then simply, correct the errors and the page should render once again.